# Fedora 15 Open VPN wont connect

Tags: openvpn, fedora-15

Ive been trying to get a VPN connection working in fedora 15 using Open VPN through network manager, I setup the connection following [this tutorial](https://vpnuk.info/setup-linux-openvpn.html).

However it doesnt connect and doesnt give me a meanigful reason why, I click to connect the vpn it then changes the network icon at the top to the icon that shows its inbetween states and it will stay like that for ever, My network connection remains and I can browse the net but the vpn is not connected.

Heres the last line of output of

> /var/log/messages

```
Jul 16 18:41:13 fed-hp NetworkManager[952]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Jul 16 18:41:13 fed-hp NetworkManager[952]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 11570
Jul 16 18:41:13 fed-hp NetworkManager[952]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Jul 16 18:41:14 fed-hp NetworkManager[952]: get_secrets: assertion `secrets_idx < SECRETS_REQ_LAST' failed
```

this will show every time I try to connect the vpn, no other vpn related stuff in there, and googling this message yields no results, Ive tried all updates and openvpn is installed

any ideas?

pic of connection state[image: network connections]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out I needed to enable the use custom gateway port and all is now good

[image]